I dont understand the differences between Plato's Forms and Husserl's essence
So Plato's essence is universal essence existing independently of us. And Husserl's essence, despite being invariant they are not universal and does not exist beyond the conscious relation to the object. I understand that for Husserl, essences "reveal" themselves only through consciousness, but they must also exist "out there" in order to reveal themselves to us? Even essence as ideals. Can someone please explain, also examples would be good.

Plato's forms are self-sufficient ideal objects that reside in a special (higher) plane of reality and shape the sensible world. Husserl's essences are invariants of perception that sentient perceiving creatures (like us, but not only) grasp in intentional acts. If anything, they are closer to Aristotle's forms than Plato's. Those are only intellectually separable from matter-form compounds (objects in the world), aspects that can be shared and transferred among them, but do not exist apart from them. Except without Aristotle's realism about the world itself apart from perceiving creatures.

Interpretative issues are not simple, taking into account that most of philosophy is recycling previous words and concepts with new meanings.
Husserl epoché produces the forms of consciousness calleds “eidē” (plural of “eidos”). And Wesensschau [eidetic intuition] is “viewing of essences”.
See also the Husserl's Ideen zu einer reinen Phänomenologie und phänomenologischen Philosophie (1913).
Thus, some of Husserl's key concept are Platonic terms.
At the same time, Husserl is clear in his rejection of the metaphysical use of "ideas"; he writes that "everyone is a 'Platonist' in a naïve way" and he rejects accusations of Platonism, rejecting every appeal to metaphysics and super-sensible power of intellectual intuition.
In Logical Investigations (1900) Husserl defines the natura of essences by opposition to the dimension of facts (Tatsachen), that are individual and temporal, while the ideal dimension is non-individual and non-temporal. But they are not innate, because are produced in intentional acts
In conclusion, as suggested by Conifold, essences are intellectually separable from individuals but do not exist by their own.
See Phenomenological Platonism: Husserl and Plato, into Alan Kim (editor), Brill's Companion to German Platonism (2019)
